Japanese gangster film w/ handgun assembly contest
I watched a Japanese-language gangster film a few years ago. I think it was made within the last 10-15 years.
The protagonist assembled some gunmen to help him kill some people who had wronged him. During a "get to know you" scene, they were having lunch on a balcony or deck. I think there were 3 people total.
Two of them put on blindfolds and raced to see how quickly they could re-assemble handguns.
Towards the end, as the sole survivor, he heads to the beach to be with the family that adopted him. There's a woman there who tends to a lot of children.
Does anyone know the film?

Sounds like the bloody Hong Kong action thriller Vengeance from 2009 with Johnny Hallyday.

In Macau, a family is attacked by three killers and only the wife survives severely wounded. Her father, the French chef Francis Costello, travels to Macau to visit his daughter in the hospital and steals the photos of his daughter, her husband and two children from the police department to seek revenge against the killers. Costello stumbles with the independent hit-men Kwai, Chu and Fat Lok that are under contract with the mobster George Fung at his hotel and he hires the trio to hunt down the killer of his daughter's family. They locate the killers in Hong Kong and they travel to kill them. But they have a surprise when they discover who ordered to kill the family.

The blindfolded gun assembly scene is there, and at some point Costello loses his memory and is left on the beach with a woman who raises orphans, which you can see a bit of in the trailer:




YES. that is definitely it. thank you!
